# Which is the best Practice for localisation ? By Using DB along with cache or Property file kept outside the war

Tags: javascript, java, database, reactjs, backend

I am developing a project using reactJS as front end technology. Wanted to know which is the best way to implement localisation.

Points to be considered is 
- When a new language is added, how , with minimal changes this can be implemented.
- Is there any other way apart from using Java resource bundle
- Using DB along with cache or Property file kept outside the war
- Is there any other way that reactJS can handle it, if yes is it a good practice

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your plans. If you're going to have more client like mobile, then database location is preferred. It saves you from duplication of code for mobile and the web apps. In such case, the database is " the only source of trust". You change only one places and it affects all clients.

But if you're sure you will have an only web client, then react location may be taken. Usually, client side i18n is implemented as plain JSON file where you map label -> translation. You can have files like

- messages.en.json
- messages.ru.json
- ....

The *messages.en.json* may look like following:

```
{
    "USER_NAME": "User name"
}
```

The *messages.ru.json* may look like following:

```
{
    "USER_NAME": "Имя пользователя"
}
```

In your code, depends on current culture, you will do like this

```
render() {
   <label>{I18Service.translate('USER_USER')}</label>
}
```